# Excel - Search and place text based on user entry

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet where the user will put in a department selected from a list. When they put in the department name, I want the department number to auto-populate in the next cell.

```
(Column A)    (Column B)
Department    Department Number 
Faclilites    1234-56
Cafeteria     4567-12
```

So, when column A is populated by user, column B will auto-fill. I currently have a sheet setup that contains all of the departments and the department number.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `VLOOKUP`.

In the cell with the dropdown, use a `VLOOKUP` that references the dropdown list as the lookup value and the Department Name/Number table as the lookup range.

```
=VLOOKUP(cell with dropdown value,lookup range,column # of department number,FALSE)
```

[image]
When a user updates the drop-down, the `VLOOKUP` will update with the correct department number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This works perfectly for what I am trying to accomplish!